# Correct way to toggle CSS classes upon element onfocus and onblur (pure JS)

Tags: javascript, css

I'm a server-side dev dabbling in a bit of JS  front-end. Recently I added a `position:fixed` menu bar in on of my web applications (meant for the mobile web).

It works fine. But there's a usability issue. When the virtual keyboard opens, the bottom menu naturally moves up with it. Sometimes, this covers up `textareas` or `inputs` the user was supposed to type into.

Now the web-app in question has a ton of user-generated content. Ergo there can be several `textareas` or `input` elements on a given page.

How do I use pure JS to set `position:absolute` on the given menu bar when **any** textarea or input is focused, and reset it to `position:fixed` when the said focus is lost (i.e. blurred)?

---

Here's how I've setup the menu bar:

```css
.design{
    background:coral;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    z-index:89;
}
.fix-it{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
.abs-it{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom_nav" class="fix-it design">
BOTTOM MENU
</div>
```

My pure JS knowledge is a work-in-progress. I'm trying to achieve my requirement via the following pure JS (and failing):

```
// selecting all textareas or inputs for processing (e.g. making fixed bottom menu 'absolute')
var input_btns = document.getElementsByClassName('inp');

// ensuring relevant CSS classes applied onfocus and onblur
for (var i=0, len=input_btns.length; i < len; i++) {
    input_btns[i].onfocus = document.getElementById("bottom_nav").classList.remove('fix-it').add('abs-it');
    input_btns[i].onblur = document.getElementById("bottom_nav").classList.remove('abs-it').add('fix-it');
}
```

---

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Upon initialization, the menu bar renders devoid of any CSS class at all!?

I'm stumped. Can an expert help me fix my code? I prefer pure JS solutions over the need to use any library for such a rudimentary task.

Comment: `[i].onfocus` must be a function. You have to assign a handler not a statement

Comment: @Rajesh: could you give a quick illustrative example so we're both on the same page?

Comment: please share complete html

Comment: @brk: Is it because you want to see what `document.getElementsByClassName('inp');` does? 'inp' is a classname I've injected in all input elements. It's a Django project and injection happens in the python side of things. I can assure you I've done that correctly (in case that's what you wanted to check)

Comment: @HassanBaig you are missing `share_btns` array and your loop depends on that

Comment: @HassanBaig This is a working code: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/v94yzjkL/12/)** I'll running late so not adding an answer. Someone please use this and add an answer, else i'll do it on monday. I have added basic comments explaining reasons

Comment: @Rajesh: Eagle eyes man! I've fixed this dumb problem. What I find is I'm unable to toggle the class name - it simply becomes empty. Maybe this sytax is to blame? `input_btns[i].onfocus = document.getElementById("bottom_nav").classList.remove('fix-it').add('abs-it');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap `document.getElementById("bottom_nav").classList.remove('fix-it').add('abs-it');` in a function, so it's only run when the event is triggered

like this:

```
    input_btns[i].onfocus = () => {
      document.getElementById("bottom_nav").classList.remove('fix-it');
      document.getElementById("bottom_nav").classList.add('abs-it');
    }
```

When you do an assignation the code after the `=` is executed immediately; what you need is a function that executes the code only when that function is called.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my concepts. Unfortunately, I still can't get the desired effect when I focus on any `input` field (i.e. the class name doesn't toggle)

Comment: I updated my answer, I don't think that `.add` and `.remove` are chainable

Comment: I marked your answer. I don't know why my question was deemed off-topic and downvoted - but you gave me a valuable answer. Normally people tend to delete their downvoted questions - but I'll let this one stay, you've earned your points. The problem really was how I was incorrectly chaining it.